# Try Catch - URL link not exist

Tags: c#, url, try-catch

I need to read some Data from URLs - but depending on the string (ICAO) - the URL does not sometimes exist (it is not valid). In this case - I should get "N/A" - but that does not work... only when all three URLs are readable - it is working.

```
        [Invoke]
    public List<Category> getWeather(string ICAO)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Category> lstcat = new List<Category>();
            Category cat = new Category();
            string fileString;
            bool isexists = FtpDirectoryExists("ftp://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/stations/" + ICAO);
            if (isexists == true)
            {
                WebClient request = new WebClient();
                string url = "http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/" + ICAO;
                byte[] newFileData = request.DownloadData(url);
                fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
                cat.Cat = "METAR";
                lstcat.Add(cat);
                cat = new Category();
                cat.Cat = fileString;
                lstcat.Add(cat);
                url = "http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/forecasts/shorttaf/stations/" + ICAO;
                newFileData = request.DownloadData(url);

                fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
                cat = new Category();
                cat.Cat = "Short TAF";
                lstcat.Add(cat);
                cat = new Category();
                cat.Cat = fileString;
                lstcat.Add(cat);

                url = "http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/forecasts/taf/stations/" + ICAO;
                newFileData = request.DownloadData(url);

                fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
                cat = new Category();
                cat.Cat = "Long TAF";
                lstcat.Add(cat);
                cat = new Category();
                cat.Cat = fileString;
                lstcat.Add(cat);

            }
            else
            {
                fileString = "N/A;N/A";
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If that FTP URL is valid, you're not going to reach the `"N/A;N/A"` string. Also, you're going through all the trouble of adding items to `List<Category> lstcat`, but then you're always returning `null`- is this really the behavior you want?

Comment: Nope. I want that for each URL - which does not response - to get a "N/A". 
Like
METAR
N/A
But it still shows the other URL content items.

Comment: Hey Bjoern- did either answer work for you? If so, please click the checkmark for one of them to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method to check the remote file exists or not.
   make a Heder request to the URl, if the sattus code is 200 or 302 then return true
    otherwise false;

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(/* url */);
request.Method = "HEAD";


try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    /* A WebException will be thrown if the status of the response is not `200 OK` */
}
finally
{
    // Don't forget to close your response.
    if (response != null)
    {
        response.Close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I see what you want to do. I re-worked your code so that it fits what's actually needed.

Right now, it seems like the first `Category` in `lstcat` has the description (such as "METAR") of the first URL, the second `Category` in `lstcat` has the `fileString` that matches it, and so on. This is very vague and cumbersome. Instead, make it so that one `Category` object contains everything you need to know about a URL:

```
public class Category 
{
    public string description;
    public string fileString;
    //Other fields you might use somewhere else...

    public Category(string description, string fileString /*, other fields, if any...*/)
    {
        this.description = description;
        this.fileString = fileString;
        //Initialize others...
    }
}
```

I then eliminated all the duplication in the original code, by putting all the URL download code into a separate function.

```
[Invoke]
public List<Category> getWeather(string ICAO)
{
    bool isexists = FtpDirectoryExists("ftp://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/stations/" + ICAO);
    if (isexists)
    {
        List<Category> lstcat = new List<Category>();

        addCategoriesToList(
            lstcat,
            "http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/" + ICAO,
            "METAR"
        );
        addCategoriesToList(
            lstcat,
            "http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/forecasts/shorttaf/stations/" + ICAO,
            "Short TAF"
        );
        addCategoriesToList(
            lstcat,
            "http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/forecasts/taf/stations/" + ICAO,
            "Long TAF"
        );

        return lstcat;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private static void addCategoriesToList(List<Category> lstcat, string url, string description)
{
    string fileString;
    //Use "using" so that `request` always gets cleaned-up:
    using (WebClient request = new WebClient()) 
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] newFileData = request.DownloadData(url);
            fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
        }
        catch
        {
            fileString = "N/A";
        }
    }

    lstcat.Add(new Category(description, fileString));
}
```

I think this accomplishes what you want, in a much cleaner and straightforward way. Please let me know if that is indeed the case!